# Proper term for a sequence that is the sequence of sums of each positional element in two sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Is there a proper English term for Z in this example?

a = [ 1, 2, 4 ]

b = [ 1, 1, 1 ]

Z = [ 2, 3, 5 ]

Comment: I'd assume "set sum" would be a sufficient term to describe Z.

Comment: @Neil: that's a fairly confusing term. What is "set" describing?

Comment: what you describe are not sets. In mathematical parlance, sets have distinct elements.

Comment: Also generally sets are not ordered.  I would call them sequences, then Z is the sum of sequences a and b.

Comment: Or vectors? Sum of vectors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can say that $Z$ is the "pointwise sum of $a$ and $b$" or "coordinate-wise sum".

This can be seen as addition in a three dimensional [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) (or free module).